# Availability of PGx Biomarker data for drug labels?

Tags: openfda, releasing-data, drugs

Is the [Pharmacogenomic Biomarkers in Drug Labeling](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/science-research-drugs/table-pharmacogenomic-biomarkers-drug-labeling) available through the OpenFDA system?

If not, are there any plans to make this data available? Seems like this would be an easy thing to model and make available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point openFDA has no plans on making Pharmacogenomic Biomarkers available in Drug Labeling.